# Can a Get method of a property take parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, properties, get

I have 2 properties in my Queries class.

```
string comboBoxFilterQuery { get { return "some query"; } }
```

and

```
//Property in question that has a WHERE clause in the query
string reportQuery { get {return "some query with parameter";} }
```

Is it possible to pass a parameter to my Get method of the above property to use in the query? The query has a Where clause, and I want that clause to be whatever is passed in.

If not, what is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, I think you're after a method.

Comment: {get; set;} is a shorthand way of creating a getter and setter method for the property.  It is equivalent to defining a larger method.  You could very easily write your own, but you'll need to add some variable to store the values.  E.g. string comboBoxFilterQuery { get { return _comboBoxFilterQuery} set { _comboBoxFilterQuery = value; }    and definte _comboBoxFilterQuery as a class variable